# Random walk issue using betweenness centrality

Tags: netlogo

I created a small network of 10 nodes and linked with each other. Then I calculated betweenness centrality of each node using network extension. 
Now, I want to implement random walk algorithm. 
First of all, when I create walkers, I want to place them on one-of nodes having max value of betweenness. 
then I want to move walker to new-location of link-neighbor having max value of betweennes.
But, I don't how to implement this logic, Kindly guide and help me.
Here is my code:

```
        extensions [ nw ]
        breed [ nodes node ]
        breed [ walkers walker ]
        walkers-own [ location ]
        to setup
        clear-all
        make-nodes
        end
        to go
        random-walk
        end
        to make-nodes
         create-nodes 10 [
         set shape "circle"
         set color white
         setxy (random-xcor * 0.95) ( random-ycor * 0.95)
         ]
         ask nodes [
         create-link-with one-of other nodes ]             
         end

         to make-walkers
          create-walkers 3 [
          set color green
         **set location one-of nodes**
          move-to location
          ]
          reset-ticks
           end
          to random-walk
           ask links [ set thickness 0 ]
           ask walkers [
          **let new-location one-of  [link-neighbors] of location**

          move-to new-location
           set location new-location
            ask location [
            set color red] 
            tick
           end

         to betweenness
         centrality [ [] -> nw:betweenness-centrality ]
         end
```

Comment: max of what? do you mean the walker starts at the node with the maximum betweenness value and then moves to whichever of its neighbours has the maximum betweenness value?What bit can't you do? Starting it at the max betweenness node? Moving it? Please try to do whatever bit you're stuck on, then come to StackOverflow with a specific question - show the code you have, describe the behaviour you are getting (or the error message) and what behaviour you want.

Comment: Yes sir, I mean the walker starts at the node with the maximum betweenness value and then moves to its neighbors have the maximum betweenness value.

Comment: okay, you need to look at the `max-with` and `max-one-of` primitives. You really need to write your code iteratively, make one piece work before writing the next piece. In your case, just get the walkers to start at the correct place before writing anything about movement.

Comment: I second the advice to start with a small amount of working code and only gradually make small additions to it, making sure everything still functions properly at every step.

Comment: The above-mentioned code is working correctly. First of all, I placed walker on the source node. i.e set location one-of node with [ source = true], to move walker according to maximum betweenness value of node, I ask walker to look their link neighbor with max label. i.e set new-location one-of [link-neighbor with-max [label] of location. It works correctly by moving to its neighbor with max value.

Comment: But, what I want is that walker should move to all others nodes, not to back its old location once visited.

Comment: Dear sir, can you guide me how to stop walker from rerouting?. @JenB

Comment: I can't see how the code works since it just randomly chooses a node to go to rather than using the betweenness information. However, if the question is about how not to return to a prior node, not about identifying what node to go to next, then you need to give the turtles a memory of what nodes they have visited and remove those nodes from consideration.